# JSF how to restrict validation to open accordion tab

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

Each of my tabs has a data table, an input and an add button. When I click the add button the validation happens on open and closed tabs. I see the errors for the closed tabs in the open tab. Is there a way to make the validation only occur in the open tab.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="pnl_accord_codetables" dynamic="true" cache="false">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{pc_Maintenence.onTabChange}" immediate="true"/>
        <c:forEach items="#{pc_Maintenence.codeMaintenenceTables}" var="codetable">
            <p:tab title="#{codetable.tableName}">

                 <util:datatable_util dataTableTemplate="#{codetable}"
                        dataTableList="#{pc_Maintenence.getDataTableList(codetable.tableList_managedBeanName.concat('.').concat(codetable.tableList_propertyName))}"
                        dataTableListItem="#{pc_Maintenence.getDataTableListItem(codetable.tableList_rowItemClassName, codetable)}"
                        actionMethodsBean="#{pc_Maintenence}"
                        buildMessagePanel="true"/>
            </p:tab>
        </c:forEach>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

This code is inside the composite

```
    <p:panel id="pnl_add" rendered="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.addRow}">
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.columns}" var="column">  
                   <p:outputLabel styleClass="outputLabel" value="#{column.heading}"
                                for="inputtext" rendered="#{column.inputForAddingRecord}"/>

                  <p:inputText value="#{(cc.attrs.dataTableListItem)[column.name]}"
                        rendered="#{column.inputForAddingRecord}" id="inputtext"
                        required="#{not empty param[cc.add.clientId] and column.required}"
                        validator="#{column.validate}"/>

                        <div class="clear">&#160;</div>
            </ui:repeat>
     </p:panel>

<p:panel id="pnl_commandbuttons">
            <p:commandButton styleCl2ass="commandButton"
                rendered="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.addRow}"
                binding="#{cc.add}"
                action="#{cc.attrs.actionMethodsBean.addRowAction(cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate)}"
                value="Add"
                update="pnl_datatable pnl_add pnl_msg @parent"
                title="Add">
                <p:collector value="#{cc.attrs.dataTableListItem}" addTo="#{cc.attrs.dataTableList}" />
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton styleClass="commandButton"
                rendered="#{cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.addRow or cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate.editable}"
                action="#{cc.attrs.actionMethodsBean.submitAction(cc.attrs.dataTableTemplate)}"
                value="Submit"
                update="pnl_datatable pnl_add pnl_msg @parent"
                title="Submit">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panel>
```

This is my validation method inside of my columns class

```
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        ResourceBundle resource = (ResourceBundle)getManagedBean("regex");
        String pattern = resource.getString(this.regexName);

        if(pattern != null){

            RegexValidator regexValidator = new RegexValidator();
            regexValidator.setPattern(pattern);
            regexValidator.validate(context, component, value);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using `c:forEach`? There are properties `value` and `var` on `p:accordionPanel` which you can use to iterate over a list to display dynamic tabs. Would you like to submit the data of all the tabs or just of the open one?

Comment: I am also using a primefaces data table in the composite code. I did not show that code to simplify the question. I am using the for each because there is a bug when using the value and var for the accordionPanel along with primeface's columns tag. The first row of second table that is built dynamically has the data from the first table that was built and the first row of the third table has the second tables data and so on. The repeat tag also has this same problem. When I put it in a for each the problem went away. I want to validate just the open tab.